# CORS error in Lyft API started recently

Tags: lyft-api

The Lyft API recently stopped adding

```
access-control-allow-origin:*
```

to the ETA and cost estimate endpoints, so it is no longer possible to get that information in the browser because of CORS restrictions. Of course, I can just grab the data on my own server, but it seems unnecessary to create an extra hop for the data. Has anyone else experienced this? Do you know if Lyft changed their policy, or was this just an accident?

https://developer.lyft.com/v1/reference#availability-driver-eta
https://developer.lyft.com/v1/reference#availability-ride-estimates

Comment: This is blocking me as well. Hopefully Lyft will review this.