# Lyft-API - GET from Localhost

Tags: vue.js, axios, lyft-api

I have been trying to figure out how to get this Vue project to work with the Lyft API. I have been able to get an Auth Token successfully created from the three-legged procedure, but I am unable to get the available drive types `https://api.lyft.com/v1/ridetypes` endpoint from the `localhost:8080`. It does work on *Postman*.

It keeps stating:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://api.lyft.com/v1/ridetypes?lat=37.7752315&lng=-122.418075'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I had tried doing a proxy using a `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/lyftapi': {
                target: 'https://api.lyft.com/v1',
                ws: true,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I been around other parts of Stack Overflow, and this is the closest thing to my problem, but no answers.

[CORS error in Lyft API started recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218569/cors-error-in-lyft-api-started-recently)

Any suggestions?

**Axios Get Call**

```
axios.get('/ridetypes', {
    baseURL: 'https://api.lyft.com/v1',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': this.lyftToken,
    },
    params: {
        lat: lat.toString(),
        lng: long.toString()
    }
})
```

If it means anything, I am able to make successful GET calls to retrieve Uber products, but not so much the Auth Token (unless its from Postman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lyft-API has disabled CORS, this means that **browsers** will block calls to `api.lyft.com`.

Vue won't be able to do anyting about this as this is a browser security policy.

Luckily there is nothing from stoping you to make this call from your own server.

One solution is to forward the request and response using your own server. You make a call to your server, the server makes a call to lyft, waits for the response and then responds your request.

This is **not a vue only solution**.

Comment: I would take it that I can do this with Node.js?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it with nodejs

Comment: I just want to confirm that I got the REST API to work on Node.js. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.